# Retaining a variables value in a loop?

Tags: php, laravel-4

In the first loop iteration I wish to set the `$parentId`, this is set from a query to the database.

I then wish to retain the value of the `$parentId` from the first loop iteration for all following loop iterations.

I've tried this but it kicks up an `error - unexpected $parentId`.

What's the correct way to approach this?

```
foreach (Config::get('wdt') as $width) {

    $query = Asset::create(array('title' =>  $data["title"]));
    !isset($parentId)$parentId = $query->id();
}
```

Comment: Try adding an "if" in there...  `if (!isset($parentID)) $parentID = $query->id();`

Comment: yeah not sure thats valid PHP?  if it is, its ugly as sin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a ternary operator:

```
foreach (Config::get('wdt') as $width) {

    $query = Asset::create(array('title' =>  $data["title"]));
    isset($parentId) ? NULL : $parentId = $query->id();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is there's no condition. Initialisation is better too. Test this :

```php
$parentId = null;
foreach (Config::get('wdt') as $width) {
    $query = Asset::create(array('title' =>  $data["title"]));
    ($parentId === null) ? $parentId = $query->id() : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you initialize the variable 'parentId' before you loop, and change the condition on interactions, see:

```
$parentId = NULL;
foreach (Config::get('wdt') as $width) {

    $query = Asset::create(array('title' =>  $data["title"]));
    ($parentId == NULL) ? $parentId = $query->id() : $parentId;
}
```